How to create npm package from react native app with native code
I have a react native app with native code.
If I try locally the app it works, with Ios and with Android.
I want to create npm package and to do that I created a .podspec file.
When I run
pod lib lint
I have this error
"- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for React-RCTAppDelegate depended upon by name_package".
Is possible to create a npm package with react native app or have I to use a react native library?
If yes, how can I fix the error?
Thanks
